# Can the flag/close button be moved back to the bottom right corner?

Tags: feature-request, design, close-dialog

The old dialogue had the button in the bottom right hand corner.

[image]

The new one now has it in the bottom left corner.

[image]

This breaks workflow for those of us used to clicking in the old spot. Whilst I could get used to it muscle memory has already failed me every time so far on both mobile and desktop and it's quite annoying.

To me, and I'm not a UX expert *at all*, bottom right made more sense. You read left to right, top to bottom. By being in the bottom right corner it is signalling it is the last thing to do/read which *it is*.

Can we move it back to the bottom right corner?

Comment: similar request on MSO: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/396585/please-move-the-flag-button-back-to-the-right-side

Comment: @rene I didn't check MSO, that post and the comments on it give some nice reasons for wanting it changed back as well.

Comment: Other buttons in similar dialogues are still in the bottom right hand corner as well. So keeping it consistent is also a reason to change it back.

Comment: Please move or copy this to https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/346638/256282